# Why does TypeScript think that string union is any string when used as a key?

Tags: typescript

Trying to use a union of strings as a key:

```
type Union = 'yes' | 'no'
const fn = (t: Union) => {
    const x: Record<Union, string> = { [t]: 'test' }
}
```

Results in an error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<Union, string>': yes, no
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigchBAzpqAHyziUwCgBjFXYKAM1QwApgAuWRFASnQD4oAb3JRRUanFpQAHhwBKEagCcAJgB54yOABootJQjgBzARkFQA2sAC6HTMDzACAX3KugA)

I would expect that type of this expression:

```
{ [t]: 'test' }
```

Is:

```
{ [x in Union]: string; }
```

And not

```
{ [x: string]: string; }
```

Comment: You know that `Record<Union, string>` is equivalent to `{yes: string; no: string}`, right?  So the value `{[t]: 'test'}` is definitely not assignable to that.  This isn't an answer to the question, but it's still a faulty premise that any answer would need to correct.  The type you're looking for is `{yes: string} | {no: string}` (which *could* be written in terms of `Union`, but not in this comment)

Comment: The answer to the question would be that this is a longstanding known bug in TS, see [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  The workaround I usually use is a helper function I call `kv()` which produces a computed prop object of the "right" type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m33x2m).  See the answers to the linked questions for more information